# SELECT varchar column with JSON data as JSON

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with couple columns and one column (let's call it `EXIF`) is `varchar` and contains a valid JSON string.

I want to select the table with `FOR JSON` and I want to include the JSON data from the `EXIF` column as a part of the JSON result.

Now the data in the `EXIF` column is returned as string and escaped in the result.

```sql
SELECT Col1, EXIF 
  FROM blah 
   FOR JSON AUTO
```

Expected:

```json
{
  "Col1": "something",
  "EXIF": {
    "GPS": "xxx"
  }
}
```

What I get instead

```json
{
  "Col1": "something",
  "EXIF": "{\"GPS\": \"xxx\"}"
}
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f1f71f6716ab3ef0d19f9aa8050daccf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved. The key was to put the `JSON_QUERY` outside the `CASE`.

not working

```
SELECT Col1,
CASE WHEN ISJSON(EXIF)=1 THEN JSON_QUERY(EXIF) END AS EXIF2
FROM BLAH
FOR JSON AUTO
```

worked

```
SELECT Col1,
JSON_QUERY(CASE WHEN ISJSON(EXIF)=1 THEN EXIF END) AS EXIF2
FROM BLAH
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JSON_QUERY()` function, *which also indicates whether the format for JSON object is valid(if not valid error returns from the select statement)*, in order to get rid of those escape characters such as

```
SELECT Col1, JSON_QUERY(EXIF) AS EXIF
  FROM blah 
   FOR JSON AUTO
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4f2071c215650df11ee502acf145ee08)</kbd>

Comment: thank you for your help and creating the demo. I have tried this before I asked but now I know why it didn't worked for me. I have a CASE ISJSON() to get rid of errors. check my demo please

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f1f71f6716ab3ef0d19f9aa8050daccf